# How can I migrate a doctrine DB in Symfony when the project is disabled

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, migrate

So I disabled my site with

```
symfony project:disable --env=prod
```

And rsynced my new code to the server.

But now when I run

```
symfony doctrine:migrate --env=prod
```

I get a warning that the site is currently unavailable.

I clearly don't want to enable the project (yet) as I first want to make it all works. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: is this still a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. This doesn't work by default. If your production database is available from your development machine you can start the migration on this machine via:

```
$> php symfony doctrine:migrate --env=prod
```

Thats what I do in my deployment scripts

Comment: From the "making sure it all works" comment, I'm not sure he has a development server to test it on. But if he does, I agree. Make sure the production database can be accessed from your development server, then run the migrate command from the development server.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably restrict access to your IP address in the index.php, such as when working in the dev environment. Enable the project and then run again.

Comment: Yeah but then anyone visiting the site doesn't get a nice "Unavailable" page